# In what circumstances are batch files the right approach?

Tags: python, batch-file

I've inherited various task with moderately confusing batch files. I intend to rewrite them as Python scripts, if only so I can thoroughly see what they're doing, as can my successors.

I honestly don't see why anyone would have more than a startling simple (under five line, do a, b, c, d, e in order) batch file: proper logic deserves a more modern approach, surely?  But am I missing something? Is there a real advantage in still using such an approach? If so, what is it?

Clarified in response to comments: Windows .bat fils, that check for existence of files in certain places and move them around and then invoke other programs based on what was found. I guess what I'm really asking is, is it normal good practice to still create batch files for this sort of thing, or is it more usual to follow a different approach?

Comment: What kind of batch file do you mean, Windows?

Comment: The advantage of .bat scripts is that they can be executed very easily.  Most don't require downloading additional components, they don't require attention to execution policy, they don't require a compiler, and they are easily shared as text snippets in forums, pastebin, etc.  It's a tool, just like Python is another tool, as is PowerShell, as is C#, etc.  For some jobs, batch scripting is the right tool.  Without your asking a more specific question, that's as good an answer as you're going to get.  This question ought to be closed as opinion-based.

Comment: In what circumstances are python files the right approach? Don't fall in the [Law of the instrument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_instrument) trap: _if all you have is a hammer, everything looks like a nail_.

Comment: @mouviciel: Awareness of this temptation was the exact motivation for asking the question: I know I hate .bat files; I don't know if my hatred is logical

Comment: @LutzHorn, hover the mouse over the [tag:batch-file] tag and you will find out...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that if I were still doing sysadmin on Windoze systems I would be replacing all but the simplest of BAT files with something -- anything! -- else. Because that particular command language is so awfully deficient in just about everything you need. (Exception handling? Block structured code? Procedures? Parsing text strings and filenames? )

Python is highly readable and "batteries included", so it has to be worthy of consideration as a Windows scripting language. However, Powershell may offer advantages with respect to interfacing to Windows components. It was designed with that in mind. With Python you'd be relying on extra modules which may or may not do all that you need, and might not be as well-supported as Python and its standard libraries. On the other hand, if it's currently done with BAT it's probably not that sophisticated!

The main argument against change is "if it ain't broke, don't fix it". So if the BAT scripts do all you need and no changes are needed, then don't make any. Not yet. (Sooner later a change *will* be needed, and that is the time to consider scrapping the BAT script and starting again).

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure this is the correct place for such question but anyway..

1. Batch files (with very slight reservations) can be ran on every windows machine since windows NT (where the `cmd.exe` was introduced). This is especially valuable when you have to deal with old machines running windows xp or 2003.(still) The most portable language between the windows machines.
2. Batch files are very fast. Especially compared to powershell.
3. Easier to call. While wsh by default is called with wscript.exe (which output is in a cumbersome pop up windows) and powershell need a policy parameters and by default double clicks won't work on powershell scripts.

I event don't think you need python except if you are aiming multi-platform scripting (i.e. macs or linux machines). Windows comes with other powerful enough languages like vbscript and javascript (since XP) . C# , Visual Basic and jscript.net (since Vista) and powershell (since windows 7). And even when you want multi platform scripts .net based languages are highly considerable as Miscrosoft already offers an official support for .net for unix. Though the best choices probably are powershell and c# as visual basic and jscript.net are in maintenance mode , though the jscript options (jscript and jscript.net) are based on javascript which in the moment is the more popular language and investing in it will worth it.

By the way all languages coming packed with the  Windows by default can be elegantly wrapped into batch file.